# An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on '%MY SERVICE ADRESS%'.

Tags: webdeploy

in fact i want to migrate my services from a server to another server ( Includes Services on IIS, IIS Settings , ... ) and for this wanted use IIS WebDeploy Feature.
but When I want to Import my WebDeploy ( That is Exported from Main server ) Occur below Error:

> " The package installation failed.
>
> Details:     An error was encountered when processing operation
>   'Create Directory' on 'D:\services...'. The
>   error code was 0x80070015. The device is not ready. "

So i search about it and common answers was about permisions but i set full control permision for IIS users ( Like networkservice , localsystem , IUSR , ... )

Please help me My friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and that was very funny because web deploy tried to unzip files To partition 'D' while Partition 'D' was 'DVD Drive' and my goal Partition Was 'E'.
So i changed it and solved my problem.